# Is there a technique to freeze gnocchi so they maintain their consistency?

Tags: freezing, dough, italian-cuisine, gnocchi

I've made gnocchi, let them dry for 2 hours over the counter, place them in a plastic container with extra flour inside the freezer.

Two days later I take them out of the freezer. After an hour the gnocchi were defrosted but **sticky** and a little bit **darker**.

Should I use semolina instead of flour after the gnocchi are shaped so they don't become sticky?

Should I use more flour for the dough I want to freeze?

Should I cook them before freezing them?

I used potato+flour+salt to make the gnocchi. No egg.

Comment: Did you freeze them after boiling or before?

Comment: I froze the gnocchi before cooking them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I typically use potato, flour and egg.

Make. Freeze.  Then, go directly from freezer to boiling water.  Do not defrost first.

Comment: +1 for no defrosting and boil *after* freeze. They will take a bit more time to cook from frozen; hopefully the texture is not adversely affected (try a double batch, freezing half!). The brief bench-rest and a little flour (from OP) before freezing will help to keep them from sticking together as much.

Answer (score 3):

I scatter them on a metal tray thinly coated with flour. Once the tray is full, it goes directly into the freezer. After the gnocchi are frozen on the tray, I dump them into a freezer bag.

If you pile them to deep in the freezer before they are frozen (ie in a bag or box) they stick together.

Out of the freezer, directly into boiling water. Do not need to let them defrost first.

*I use richotta, but the same should apply to potato gnocchi